# TensorFlow MovingAverageOptimizer compatibility between V1 and V2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, moving-average

I have the following optimizer which was originally written in TensorFlow 1.X

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(AdamOptimizer()
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.MovingAverageOptimizer(optimizer, average_decay=moving_average_decay)
```

But now I am forced to use Tensorflow 2.2, and I tried to migrate everything so that it would support all functionality of v1. 
I have managed to "fix" AdamOptimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer()
```

But I can not find any implementation of MovingAverage(). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find it in the meantime?
Would be nice for others (like me) if you could answer your own question then!

Answer (score 0):

As per TensorFlow v1 [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib):

> The tf.contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0. Many of
> its submodules have been integrated into TensorFlow core, or spun-off
> into other projects like tensorflow_io, or tensorflow_addons.

So, use the [tensorflow-addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons) package where the implementation of [MovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/MovingAverage) exists.

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

then

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
my_ma = tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage(tf.train.AdamOptimizer(...), average_decay=...)
```